# why nano sleeps are not accurate in virtual machines

Tags: c, linux, archlinux

I want to check how accurate is nanosleep(), so I have written a program with 4 steps while (1),

1. Get the current time in nanosecond
2. do sleep for nanoseconds 100 000
3. Get the current time in nanosecond
4. check the difference of time in step 3 and step-1.

Expected Output: The diffence should be around 100,000 nano seconds but instead it shows > 1 milli seocnds at times.

### Output prints from sample program :

Granularity fails nanosec diff:1,696,699.

Granularity fails nanosec end nano :340672813 , start nano: 338976114

Note : I have observed this ~2 times in one seconds which means around 2 out of 10000 times. the sleep time goes beyond 1 milli seonds instead 100 micro seconds. This behavior seen both Virtual machine and Baremetal

Please help me with reasons and alternative approach or way to fine tune the sleep granularity.

OS : Linux Fedora-23 Centos-7.1

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, what does the o/p & O/P mean? Please [edit] your question so we can understand it better...

Comment: Neither your host os nor your guest os is a realtime operating system. There are multiple layers of scheduling in play. The description of `nanosleep` is that it "suspends  the  execution  of  the calling thread until...at least the time specified in *req has elapsed".  See that "at least" part?

Comment: Did you compare with the same program running on Linux directly installed on the same computer (vs Linux running on some VM)? I don't think you should expect your hardware to be able to reliably sleep for 100 µs, which is a too small delay. So try with a larger delay (e.g. 50 milliseconds).

Comment: `nanosleep()` suspends execution for *at least* the time specified, or until interrupted by a signal.  It is furthermore limited by the resolution resolution of the underlying clock, and after the sleep completes, there may be a delay before the thread in which it was called is scheduled again.

Comment: Use a "real-time" ([`SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html)) scheduling policy and sufficiently high priority for the thread that requires smaller granularity. I don't know if 0.1ms is achievable on typical Linux systems (it also depends on the kernel configuration); needing that almost always indicates the overall design is bad. For example, you do not use an userspace process to flip GPIO pins to generate a stable 5kHz square wave. If you need sub-millisecond delays, you're usually doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks all for the comment, here I am looking solution, for the thread which runs continiously if needed thread execution stops (releasing CPU) only for 100 micro seconds not more than that at all.  Is it possible with LINUX machine ? if yes how  can we achieve this ?